# Projects in DNA Computing

Tags: genetics, dna, bioinformatics, computational-model

I am physicist and have recently heard about DNA computing. I want to work in this area.
I want your ideas on a "feasible but new project" (maximum time I can put on the project: 6 Months ), I can work on.
(I have already heard about songs, image storage on DNA and don't want to repeat the same process for some other song or image).

Comment: [DNA computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_computing) is a branch of computing, not biology. I am voting to close as off-topic.

Comment: Note that asking for research ideas is likely to be close as off-topic even when asked on the right SE site. If someone has a good novel idea for a research project she/he would probably not give it away to a random stranger.

Comment: Hi @ParasKoundal and Welcome to Stack Exchange. SE is a bit different than some other sites, questions need to be fairly specific and have factual answers. "What do you think..." questions will usually be closed quickly. Specific questions about the chemistry of DNA computing might theoretically be on-topic in [Chemistry SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/) but I don't see any there yet. There are several SE sites related to computing and math and physics as well. In fact there are almost [200 Stack Exchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#name) to choose from. Have fun!

Comment: You mostly need to learn which machines and what budget permits a certain type of program in DNA form. you can try biostars forum. https://singularityhub.com/2018/07/24/dna-computing-gets-a-boost-with-this-machine-learning-hack/#sm.001305vt3155je0yvct1toklipjuy